# Flutter- code installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development

Tags: ios, flutter

In my macbook

1.Already installed Xcode.

2.Already excuted

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

command line .

3.Check `xcode command line tools` have selected the correct xcode version.

4.Check Xcode.app in root Applications floder and App name is `Xcode.app`, no other version mark.

---

But still get the error as tilte mentioned.

Anyone can help me, please.

[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWKq8.png)

[Xcode command line Tools setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbzBF.png)

[Xcode path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTYlt.png)

Comment: What version of flutter have you installed

Comment: @Danny Flutter 3.0.1 • channel stable

Comment: @Danny Thanks for your replying, i have found the issue.In my environment variable, i have setted `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1`, i don't know why i set this, maybe in other app, it needed to be setted.